# collatz sequence - try except; float number input

Tags: collatz

i was trying to make a simple collatz sequence
 with the following code

```
number = int(input("Please insert number: \n"))
def collatz():
        if number % 2 == 0:
            print(number // 2)
        elif number % 2 == 1:
            print(number * 3 + 1)
collatz()
```

so, if number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value. If number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1..
the excercise also asks me to implement try & except statements if the user inputs a float. My idea was as following:

```
number = int(input("Please insert number: \n"))
def collatz():
        if number % 2 == 0:
            print(number // 2)
        elif number % 2 == 1:
            print(number * 3 + 1)
try:
    collatz()
except ValueError:
    print(abs(number))
```

it doesn't work giving me

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.2'

although the try except statement what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The code throwing the error needs to be inside of the `try` block. If `int` is throwing, that's what needs to be in the `try`.

Comment: amazing! thank you @Carcigenicate